# React Native Multipart XMLRequest - Unrecognized FormData part

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to upload some files to my website. The below code works when it's a normal API request (No attachments included). But when I try to upload a file, I keep on getting this error response: `"Unrecognized FormData part."`.

```
export function HTTPRequest({body = {}, url = '', method = "POST", headers = {}, attachments = [], DEBUG = false}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const attachmentsCount = Object.keys(attachments).length * 1
    const ContentType = 0 < attachmentsCount ? "multipart/form-data" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    const submitXML = (xhrBody) => {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhr.open(method, url)
      headers["Content-Type"] = ContentType
      //headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
      for(var h in headers) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(h, headers[h])
      }
      xhr.addEventListener('load', (res) => {
        switch(res.target.status) {
            case 200: return resolve(DEBUG ? res.target.response : JSON.parse(res.target.response))
            default: return reject(res)
        }
      }, false)
      xhr.onerror = e => reject(e)
      xhr.send(xhrBody)
    }

    switch(attachmentsCount) {
        case 0:
          var request = JSON.stringify(body)
          submitXML(request)
        break
      default:
        let xhrBody = new FormData()
        xhrBody.append("_photosCount", String(attachmentsCount))
        attachments.map((file, i) => {
        xhrBody.append('file', {name: file.name, src: file.src, type: file.type})
        })
        xhrBody.append('data', body)
        console.log(xhrBody);
        submitXML(xhrBody)
    }
  })
}
```

This is the FormData Object once I tried to log it:

```
    0:"file"
    1: Object
    name:"FB_IMG_1498693908215.jpg"
 src:"content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F175865/ORIGINAL/NONE/1351181913"
    type:"image/jpeg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the Content-Type header to `multipart/form-data` without the parameter that describes the multipart boundary marker.

Leave the Content-Type header alone. Let XMLHttpRequest generate it from the FormData object.

Comment: It worked thanks. But am I not adding the parameters that describe the multipart boundary marker when I append the file data?

Comment: @Raymond — Not to the content-type HTTP header which you explicitly specified without including the boundary parameter in it. The data itself has boundaries, but the parser doesn't know what they are.